# PHP How to add multiple entries into database with checkbox form? Form only enters last entry?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, checkbox

Here's my code, not sure what I'm doing wrong here... First I check for the passed variable and add the bit about how to handle the form...

```
// Check for a user id:
if (empty($_POST['user_id'])) {
    $errors[] = 'Oops! You forgot to enter your users.';
} else {
    $user_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['user_id']));
}

if (empty($errors)) { // If everything's good.

        // Add the user to the database:
        $q = "INSERT INTO users (user_id, page_id, account_id ) VALUES ('$user_id', '$page_id', '$id' )";
        $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

        //CLOSE UP THE SUBMIT CONDITIONAL
```

Then I select the users and echo the form

```
echo '<form action="addusers.php" method="post">';
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($show, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            echo '<p><label for="learner">Add</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="user_id" value="' . $row['user_id'] . '" name="user_id" /></p>';
    }

echo '<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />
<input type="hidden" name="account_id" value="$id" />
<input type="hidden" name="course_id" value="$course_id" />
</form>';
```

This creates a list of my users, and allows me to select as many as I like, but when I click to submit, it only enters the last user into the database, not all of them?

// UPDATE
Okay- I've edited the code so that the value of the checkbox is an array and know I need to use the foreach loop to pass the variables into the database, but could someone check this code for that insert?

```
    // Add the user to the database:
$q = "INSERT INTO users (user_id) VALUES ('$user_id')";
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    if ($r->execute(Array($key, $value))){
        echo "user added <br />";
    }
} // end for each loop
```

Comment: Check that you have more than 1 user in the DB. Also, what is in `$show`?

Comment: There is more than 1 user, tho only 1 at a time is being entered. The $show variable is a reference to my code to select the users for the form. This is working fine and I didn't include it to save space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this replace

```
<input type="checkbox" id="user_id" value="' . $row['user_id'] . '" name="user_id" /></p>';
```

by

```
<input type="checkbox" id="user_id" value="' . $row['user_id'] . '" name="user_id[]" /></p>';
```

// try to make your user_id checkbox as array like `user_id[]`

Comment: I tried this solution but it only entered a value of 0 into my database for the 'user_id' ? is there anything I need to do on that first box of code (the validation and form handling) to let it know it's an array or does the [] alone do it?

Comment: in next page u must use loop to access these values

Comment: So how do I modify my INSERT function? Do I just add the [] to the end of the user_id variable?

Comment: use foreach loop and inside foreach loop use your insert query

Comment: Sorry - still having trouble with this, I get an error which reads "Duplicate entry '0' for key 1"... I've posted the code I used above in an edit to my question

Comment: try this foreach($_POST['user_id'] as $userID) { 
     $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (user_id) VALUES ('$userID')); 
}

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="user_id" value="' . $row['user_id'] . '" name="user_id[]" />
```

(note the [] after user_id in the "name" attribute).

That will cause $_POST['user_id'] to be an array of values, one for each checked checkbox.

Comment: I tried this solution but it only entered a value of 0 into my database for the 'user_id' ? is there anything I need to do on that first box of code (the validation and form handling) to let it know it's an array or does the [] alone do it?

Comment: @WillHerndon:You have to loop through $_POST['user_id'] while inserting record

Comment: So how do I modify my INSERT function? Do I just add the [] to the end of the user_id variable?